# База данных под swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Пишу приложение на swift под ios. Необходима бд для хранения локальных файлов (объектов класса). Есть кнопка добавления в "Мои занятия", при клике на нее в бд к существующим (добавленным) занятиям добавляется новое. Также необходима проверка на уникальность объекта. Какую бд использовать для такой задачи?

Comment: SQLite с оберткой FMDB
CoreData
Realm. 
Самая простая в понимании это realm, но на сколько мне известно она не реляционная база данных.

Answer (score 2):

Так вы сохраняете что-то, например, объект myObject: MyClass:

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(myObject, forKey: "MyKey")
```

а так получаете то что сохранили:

```
let myObject = Userdefaults.standatd.object(forKey: "MyKey") as! MyClass
```

Для более подробной инфы про это читайте [документацию тут](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults) Это самый простой и легкий в понимании вариант хранения состояний приложения. Но это ключ-значение хранилище. Оно плохо подходит для сложных операций с сохраненными данными.
Можно вот так красиво подвязать переменную к UserDefaults:

```
var myObject: MyClass {
     get {return UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "myObject") as! MyClass}
     set {UserDefaults.standard.set(forKey: "myObject")}
}
```

Но если данных много, они сложные и нужна действительно полноценная БД, то вам надо читать про CoreData - это локальная БД на устройстве, или пользоваться сторонним облачными решениями типа FireBase от гугла. Но дать вам примеры для пользования ими тут, в рамках ответа на вопрос, не получится из-за обширности информации, которое вы должны знать, перед тем как пользоваться этими решениями.

Comment: Вы забыли уточнить, что просто так объект в UserDefaults не записать, объект должен соответствовать протоколу Codable для того, чтобы его можно было преобразовать его в NSData.

Comment: я именно для этого приложил ссылку на документацию от UserDefaults, но в любом случае спасибо за полезное уточнение...